# How to calculate total price depending on the selected radio button

Tags: javascript, forms

I have this form:

```html
<form>
        <div  role="group" aria-labelledby="info">
        <p id="info"> Datos de clientes</p>
         <label class="data-label">Nombre
          <input type="name" name="nombre" >
          </label>
          <label class="data-label">Email
          <input type="email" name="email" >
           </label>
          <label class="data-label">Numero de personas
          <input type="number" min="1" name="number" value="number">
          </label>
        </div>  
        <div  role="group" aria-labelledby="destino-info">
            <p id="destino-info">Destino:</p>
            <label class="destino-label">
              <input type="radio" name="destino" value="destino"  onClick="changeFormula(1)" checked >
              Cuidad</label>
            <label class="destino-label">

            <input type="radio" name="destino" value="mantaña"  onClick="changeFormula(2)" > Montaña </label>
            <label class="destino-label">

            <input type="radio" name="destino" value="playa"  onClick="changeFormula(3)" >Playa</label>
            <button type="submit">Calcular tarifa</button></div>
      </form>

 <h3>El precio:</h3>
```

On submit, I need to calculate the total price depending on the number of people and type of holiday. For example, the price of the city is 100, the mountains - 130, and the beach - 150.

I don't understand how to change the cost depending on the selected radio button.

Here is what I tried, but now i feel lost:

```js
const price =[
    {cost:100},
    {cost:130},
    {cost:150}
];

function CalculateTotal(){
    let numberOfGuests = document.getElementsByName("number").value;
    let typeOfDestiny =document.getElementsByName("destino")
    let total =numberOfGuests*typeOfDestiny;
}
```

Comment: If this is your target layout and you dont wanna change nothing, then you can store the index that is passed to changeFormula in some local/global variable like **index_of_user_chosen_destination** and use it to select the price object from **price** array

And note that destino is more of a destination than destiny

Answer (score 2):

Since your radio button values are the type of vacation, you will need to look-up the cost by that type. You should change your `price` array into an object so that you can find the cost by type.

You can also throw in a currency formatter for good measure.

```js
const form = document.forms.vacation;
const totalElement = document.querySelector('#total');

const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});

const costLookup = {
  'destino' : { cost: 100 },
  'mantaña' : { cost: 130 }, 
  'playa'   : { cost: 150 }
};

function CalculateTotal(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const numberOfGuests = form.elements.number.value;
  const typeOfDestiny = costLookup[form.elements.destino.value].cost;
  const total = numberOfGuests * typeOfDestiny;
  totalElement.textContent = currencyFormatter.format(total);
  return false;
}
```

```css
button[type="submit"] { display: block; }
.data-label { display: grid; grid-template-columns: 10em 1fr; }
#destino-info { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<form id="vacation" onSubmit="CalculateTotal(event)">
  <div role="group" aria-labelledby="info">
    <p id="info">Datos de clientes</p>
    <label class="data-label">Nombre
      <input type="name" name="nombre" >
    </label>
    <label class="data-label">Email
      <input type="email" name="email" >
     </label>
    <label class="data-label">Numero de personas
      <input type="number" min="1" name="number" value="number">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div role="group" aria-labelledby="destino-info">
    <p id="destino-info">Destino:</p>
    <label class="destino-label">
      <input type="radio" name="destino" value="destino" checked >
      Cuidad
    </label>
    <label class="destino-label">
      <input type="radio" name="destino" value="mantaña">
      Montaña
    </label>
    <label class="destino-label">
      <input type="radio" name="destino" value="playa">
      Playa
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Calcular tarifa</button></div>
</form>

<h3>El precio:</h3>
<div id="total"></div>
```

You could also use data attributes i.e. `data-cost` instead of keeping an in-memory mapping of prices. Be aware that you will have to find the `:checked` radio button to access the attribute.

```js
const form = document.forms.vacation;
const totalElement = document.querySelector('#total');

const currencyFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'currency',
  currency: 'USD',
});

function CalculateTotal(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const numberOfGuests = +form.elements.number.value;
  const checked = form.querySelector('input[name="destino"]:checked');
  const destinationCost = +checked.getAttribute('data-cost');
  const total = numberOfGuests * destinationCost;
  totalElement.textContent = currencyFormatter.format(total);
  return false;
}
```

```css
button[type="submit"] { display: block; }
.data-label { display: grid; grid-template-columns: 10em 1fr; }
#destino-info { display: inline-block; }
```

```html
<form id="vacation" onSubmit="CalculateTotal(event)">
  <div role="group" aria-labelledby="info">
    <p id="info">Datos de clientes</p>
    <label class="data-label">Nombre
      <input type="name" name="nombre" >
    </label>
    <label class="data-label">Email
      <input type="email" name="email" >
     </label>
    <label class="data-label">Numero de personas
      <input type="number" min="1" name="number" value="number">
    </label>
  </div>
  <div role="group" aria-labelledby="destino-info">
    <p id="destino-info">Destino:</p>
    <label class="destino-label">
      <input type="radio" name="destino" value="destino" data-cost="100" checked >
      Cuidad
    </label>
    <label class="destino-label">
      <input type="radio" name="destino" value="mantaña" data-cost="130">
      Montaña
    </label>
    <label class="destino-label">
      <input type="radio" name="destino" value="playa" data-cost="150">
      Playa
    </label>
    <button type="submit">Calcular tarifa</button></div>
</form>

<h3>El precio:</h3>
<div id="total"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try below code and add **id="number" to Numero de personas** field and change **value="Cuidad" to Cuidad** radio button.

```js
const priceList = [{ destination: "Cuidad", cost: 100 },{ destination: "mantana", cost: 130 },{ destination: "playa", cost: 150 },];
const TOTAL_PRICE_HEADING = 'El precio:';

    function calculateTarifa() {
        const slectedDestination = document.querySelector("input[name='destino']:checked").value;
        const idx = priceList.findIndex((place) => place.destination === slectedDestination);
        if (idx >= 0) {
            const numGuests = document.getElementById("numGuests").value;
            const totalCost = priceList[idx].cost * (numGuests * 1);
            updateTotalCost(totalCost);
        }
    }

    function updateTotalCost(cost) {
        const totalCostElement = document.querySelector('h3');
        totalCostElement.innerText = `${TOTAL_PRICE_HEADING} ${cost}`;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div role="group" aria-labelledby="info">
            <p id="info">Datos de clientes</p>
            <label class="data-label">Nombre
                <input type="name" name="nombre" />
            </label>
            <label class="data-label">Email
                <input type="email" name="email" />
            </label>
            <label class="data-label">Numero de personas
                <input type="number" min="1" id="numGuests" name="number" value="number" />
            </label>
        </div>
        <div role="group" aria-labelledby="destino-info">
            <p id="destino-info">Destino:</p>
            <label class="destino-label">
                <input type="radio" name="destino" value="Cuidad" checked />
                Cuidad</label>
            <label class="destino-label">
                <input type="radio" name="destino" value="mantana" />
                Montaña
            </label>
            <label class="destino-label">
                <input type="radio" name="destino" value="playa" />Playa</label>
            <button type="button" onclick="calculateTarifa()">
                Calcular tarifa
            </button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <h3>El precio:</h3>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: and how can i make the result appear here?  <h3>El precio:</h3>   i did like this <h3>El precio:`${totalCost}`</h3>  but it is doesnt work

Comment: Updated the script, try now

Answer (score 0):

Here's another (hopefully easier) way of looking at it. You can store the cost of these things directly in the HTML element as a [dataset property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset). Then apply a click listener that will calculate the total each time one of them is clicked.

```js
let total = 0;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-cost]').forEach(r => {
    r.addEventListener('click', e => runCalc(e));
    if (r.checked) runCalc({target: r});
  })

  document.querySelector('#form').addEventListener('submit', e => {
    e.preventDefault(); // don't submit
    let chosendest = document.querySelector('[data-cost]:checked');
    console.log(`the selected destination is ${chosendest.value} for $${chosendest.dataset.cost}`);
  })
})

const runCalc = e => {
  let total = +e.target.dataset.cost;
  let loc = e.target.value
  document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML = `<h2>Going to the ${loc} will cost ${total}</h2>`;
}
```

```html
<form id="form">

  <div role="group" aria-labelledby="destino-info">
    <p id="destino-info">Destino:</p>
    <label class="destino-label">
              <input type="radio" name="destino" value="destino"  data-cost="100" checked >
              Cuidad</label>
    <label class="destino-label">
           
            <input type="radio" name="destino" value="mantaña"  data-cost="120" > Montaña </label>
    <label class="destino-label">
           
            <input type="radio" name="destino" value="playa"  data-cost="130" >Playa</label>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Calcular tarifa</button>

</form>

<div id='total'></div>
```

Comment: cool, you are a genius!!! but if I want to calculate  after submitting the form <button type="submit">Calcular tarifa</button></div>  ? Do I need to hang this function const runCalc = e => {
  let total = +e.target.dataset.cost;
  let loc = e.target.value
  document.querySelector('#total').innerHTML = `<h2>Going to the ${loc} will cost ${total}</h2>`;
} on onSubmit="runCalc()"?

Comment: I added a bit of code to make the form submit part clearer.